# FIXED htaccess rewriterule gives 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite /test to /test.php. If I go to the link directly it will give me the php page that works but when I go to /test it just gives a 404 not found error. I have enabled mod_rewrite and given the /var/www 755 permissions.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test test.php [NC]
```

test.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/test.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

FIXED: Changed FollowSymLinks to +FollowSymLinks

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RewriteLogLevel` you will see what the server does. In your case, you will see a `applying pattern '^test' to uri '/test'`. Update your rule to :

```
RewriteRule ^/test$ /test.php [NC]
```

Comment: Still not finding the file

Comment: Activate the rewrite logs to see exactly what your server does and why it doesn't match. I tested this one on my server before posting the answer, you should be close to your solution.

Comment: In this log, you try to load `test.php` which doesn't match `^/?test.html$`. Isn't your question about loading `/test` and accessing `/test.php` ?